Cannot connect to couchbase cluster created with docker compose
I am writing a java application that connects to the couchbase. Application cannot connect to database because it is necessary to create new cluster. I got Connection refused error. How can I handle it?
dockerfile
FROM openjdk:21-jdk

ADD target/todolist-app.jar todolist-app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/todolist-app.jar"]

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: 'couchbase:7.6.0'
    restart: always
    container_name: db
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    ports:
      - 8091:8091
      - 8092:8092
      - 8093:8093
      - 8094:8094
      - 11210:11210
    networks:
      - my-network

  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
    container_name: todolist-app
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge

When I run couchbase server in the docker container I could see below screen

I can't say for sure, but my guess is that your application is trying to connect before Couchbase has had time to get fully started. Couchbase is very asynchronous in its architecture, so it won't always be immediately ready even when the container is running. Assuming you're doing this for automated testing purposes, I'd recommend checking out https://github.com/brantburnett/couchbasefakeit and/or  https://github.com/testcontainers

What connection string are you using in your app?

The couchbasefakeit and testcontainers tools recommended by Matthew are great because they both pre-initialize the Couchbase Server cluster, so you don't need to worry about that step. If those tools don't meet your requirements, you can initialize the Couchbase Server cluster yourself by sending an HTTP POST to the /clusterInit endpoint described here: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/rest-api/rest-initialize-cluster.html

Alternatively, check out this Couchbase blog article that demonstrates how to create a custom pre-initialized Couchbase Server Docker image: https://www.couchbase.com/blog/couchbase-using-docker-compose/

@ozdem you do need to click Setup new Cluster and go though the wizard to make sure your cluster is ready to accept connections.
